# Why my website is not accessible with www after mapping namecheap domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, namecheap

I have a domain on `Namecheap` and hosted my front-end on `s3` bucket. So i made a `Route53` hosted zone and then created a `SSL` certificate for that domain. After that i create a `cloudfront` distribution for my domain. Now my website is accessible with `https://referling.com/` only. And also my website is accesible with my `cloudfront` domain like `*******.net` but my website is not accessible with `www`. I don't know why it is happening. Can you tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I can give exact solutions if you share your dns records. But for now you need to create dns record of cname with "host" www and "value" will be your domain *******.net.

Please check it may work.

One important thing is If you connecting s3 with route53 then you have to create two bucket one for root domainname.com and 2nd for subdomain www.domainname.com.

To configure a redirect request On the Amazon S3 console, in the Buckets list, choose your subdomain bucket ( www.example.com in this example).
follow steps
 1. Choose Properties 
 2. Choose Static website hosting
 3. Choose Redirect requests
 4. In the Target bucket or domain box, enter your domain (for example, example.com)
 5. In the Protocol box, enter http
 6. Choose save.

You can check for complete reference.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-configure-redirect

Comment: The problem is that when i changed nameservers for cloudfront on namecheap so after that i am not seeing dns records on namecheap `Advanced DNS`. And i don't know why it is happening.

Comment: Its simple, If you are setting up route53 with external domain service provider all you need to set nameservers. All the dns records will manage on aws hosted zone. Can you share aws hosted zone dns records?

Comment: Yes i did the same. But my website is not accessible with www

Comment: I have included my `hosted zone` records in my question post. Please check that

Comment: I need to look on your aws record set you created for your hosted zone. Please share

Comment: I have shared in my question. Please see the uploaded image

Comment: One important thing is If you connecting s3 with route53 then you have to create two bucket one for root domainname.com and 2nd for subdomain www.domainname.com. I hope you did it

Comment: But i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lB4DTqMEumY  and in this tutorial he only made just one bucket with domain.com

Comment: I am using cloudfront.. the article you shared in that cloudfront is not using. I am using cloudfront with ssl certificate.

Comment: Follow the above solution which I shared with you. You need to create another s3 bucket for www request. And it will redirect to https://referling.com.

Comment: I need atleast 50 point to access chat option here. But you can contact me on fiverr.
https://www.fiverr.com/users/shivccs

I will help you for your problem.